# How can I convert pandas string column into string series without text getting trimmed?

Tags: python, pandas, series

How can I convert pandas string column into string series without text getting trimmed?

```
   s = pd.Series('Data was not intuitive and too difficult for our marketing team to use. Big-Data has been a huge improvement.')
```

When convert Series into string. It gets trimmed.

```
d = s.to_string(index=False)
d = 'Sprinklr was not intuitive and too difficult f...'
```

I want to use this series to count words in it. But getting trimmed is coming in my way.

Comment: A Series takes an iterable/sequence... of which a `str` type is one... did you perhaps mean: `series = pd.Series(['Data was not intuitive and too difficult for our marketing team to use. Big-Data has been a huge improvement.'])` so you then have a series of one element instead of one consisting of N many characters?

Comment: @JonClements What version are you on? It creates a single row Series on 0.23.4.

Comment: Why do you want to call `to_string` when you could just do `s[0]` to print out the whole thing?

Comment: @coldspeed oh yeah... and you thought you were getting tired :) Guess it's the old display formatting stuff... `s[0]` will do it...

Comment: @ni3 Do `s = s[0]`. Your Series will store as str.

Comment: @JonClements Thank you All! It solved my issue.